# git rebase -i HEAD~N, OK for removing pushed (private) data?

Tags: git, github

While testing some code I forgot to remove the testing endpoint on the public repository, for example, the code initially had:

```
endpoint: http://yourendpoint.tld
```

And after I did some tests I didn't remove my endpoint:

```
endpoint: http://my-endpoint.tld
```

I fixed with another commit and set it back to its original value, but in the git history my endpoint still existed "like expected"

In my intention to clean history, remove my changes  from the previous commits, what I did was a rebase, something like:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Then I forced a push:

```
git push -f
```

I checked the history and now I see no traces of my `endpoint`, but wondering if this ok, or if I should something extra to ensure that in the remote server there are no traces of my data.

Mainly asking since in some posts I see the use `filter-branch`, for example:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch MyPasswordFile' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: Until next gc run on remote, I'd say probably it is there but not reachable from outside that remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a default server setup, `rebase -i` followed by `push -f` is sufficient to make the private data invisible to clients, provided that no other ref (branch or tag) points to the original branch head.

It is important that the server has `uploadarchive.allowUnreachable` set to `false` (or unset, because `false` is the default value). This ensures that only commits that are reachable from the refs can be requested by clients.